# Ember.js Routes: Dynamic segments in url error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My Router looks like:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('index', {path: '/'})
    this.resource('products', function () {
        this.route('all', {path: '/'});
        this.resource('products.edit', {path: '/edit/:id'}, function () {
            this.route('general');
            this.route('images');
            this.route('reviews');
        });
    });
    this.resource('category', function () {
        this.route('all', {path: '/'});
        this.resource('category.edit', {path: '/edit/:category_id'}, function () {
            this.route('general');
            this.route('images');
            this.route('products_of_category');
        });
    });
});
```

In navigation menu I have Add/Edit `Product` and Add/Edit `Category` and they linked to `products.edit` and `category.edit` routes. But when I render page I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: newHandlerInfo is undefined
```

When I remove slugs `:product_id` and `:category_id` it works fine.

Here are my models:

```
App.Product = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    productName: null,
    dateAdded: null,
    description: null,
    price: null,
    status: null,
    categories: [],
    categoryNames: []
});

App.Category = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    categoryName: null,
    dateAdded: null,
    description: null,
    children: [],
    parent: null,
    products: []
});
```

Comment: you can't have 2 resources with category, category.edit is a rout, define it as such, this.rout('edit') you can nest routes now.

Comment: I solved the problem. I didn't bind model to routes with dynamic segment. You must use model and serialize hooks in your route.

Comment: Regardless, your router is messy, edit should be a route

Comment: Wont work like that. I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a router like this is what you want:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.resource('products', function() {
    this.route('all', {path: '/'});

    this.route('edit_general', {path: '/edit/:product_id/general'});
    this.route('edit_images', {path: '/edit/:product_id/images'});
    this.route('edit_reviews', {path: '/edit/:product_id/reviews'});
  });
  this.resource('category', function() {
    this.route('all', {path: '/'});
    this.route('edit_general', {path: '/edit/:category_id/general'});
    this.route('edit_images', {path: '/edit/:category_id/images'});
    this.route('edit_products', {path: '/edit/:category_id/products'});
  });
});
```